# What happened to ec2-api-tools? Is there an easy way to migrate dependant scripts

Tags: aws-cli, ec2-api-tools

So I have a load of scripts which use ec2-api-tools.  Our infosec people have identified an issue in one of the included libraries, that comes with it.  So I've gone on the hunt for a current updated version.

However, it seems that the version I have, dated 2015, is the most current version.  If I search aws for ec2-api-tools, it directs me to aws-cli which is something different.

Has anyone else noticed this?  What happened to ec2-api-tools?  Has anyone documented what needs to be done to change scripts that use the old form (ie ec2-describe-images <options>), to use the new form (aws ec2 describe-images <options)?  From what I can see, the new form expects you to run aws configure to setup things like region and secrets.  However I want to pass those things on the command line.  Is this something others have done?  Can I simply use the same old parameters on the new aws command?